# GWT - Firing native KeyPressEvent doesn't work?

Tags: gwt

I want to replace a special entered character (e.g. 'A') with another one (e.g. 'B') when a user entering data in a TextBox or TextArea. My code is like below:

```
public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {       

    if (event.getNativeEvent().getCharCode() == 65 /*for 'A'*/){            
        event.preventDefault(); 
        NativeEvent event1 = 
        Document.get().createKeyPressEvent(false, false, false, false, 66 /* for 'B'*/);                        
        DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(event1, theTextBox);       
}
```

I think it should be OK (according to GWT docs), but in fact it just work until `event.preventDefault();` and the rest seems ignored. I mean it just removes 'A' but doesn't fire for 'B'. Can anyone tell me the reason? or any other solution? 
 Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess: have you tried moving `preventDefault` after `fireNativeEvent`?

Comment: @Darthenius Your guess leads to Firefox crash. I changed the way an tried to implement an editor action. I mean on keypress, instead of firing new event, I get the textbox value (`getValue()`), replace the entered character with new one and call `setValue()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to switch from `KeyPressHandler` to `KeyDownHandler`.

```
public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
    if( event.getNativeKeyCode() == 65 ) {
        //do the character replacement here
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.